# how to know which email receipt is failure for what reason in apache camel api

Tags: java, apache-camel

i am sending the email using apache camel api.

```
   public boolean sendEmail(JSONObject data) 
    { 
            boolean status=false; 
            camel = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
            template = camel.createProducerTemplate(); 

            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
            map.put("To",data.getString("toaddress")); 
            String body = data.getString("body"); 
            map.put("Subject", data.getString("subject")); 
            map.put("From", "xxxxxxx@yahoo.com"); 


            template.sendBodyAndHeaders("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?username=sxxx@gmail.com&password=ixxx", body, map); 

            status=true; 
            return status; 

    }
```

This code is working fine for sending single receipt as well as multiple receipt but the problem is that how do i know which email receipt is fail and for what reason.i am new in apache camel so i do not know whether apache camel is proving or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have used `ProducerTemplate.html#sendBodyAndHeaders(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.util.Map)` to send the body to the endpoint.As per the documentation, this method will throw `CamelExecutionException` - if the processing of the exchange failed. So, put this code inside try catch block

```
     public boolean sendEmail(JSONObject data) 
        { 
           boolean status=false; 
           camel = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
           template = camel.createProducerTemplate(); 
           Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
           map.put("To",data.getString("toaddress")); 
           String body = data.getString("body"); 
           map.put("Subject", data.getString("subject")); 
           map.put("From", "xxxxxxx@yahoo.com"); 
        try{
           template.sendBodyAndHeaders("smtps://smtp.gmail.com?username=sxxx@gmail.com&password=ixxx", body, map); 
        }catch(CamelExecutionException camelExecException){
        logger.error("Error occured during sending body to end point :"+ camelExecException.getMessage());
        }
}
```

This will help you find when there is a failure and the reason behind it. Hope this helps

Comment: i am new in apache camel so can you tell me actually where i need to modify my code

Comment: k.for one receipt its working fine.if any error then exception will generated but when i send to multiple receipt then its does not throw any exception even that email id is invalid

Comment: CamelExecutionException occurs only when your code is not able to do the processing of the exchange. it will not throw CamelExecutionException for invalid email id or any issues after the exchange processing.

Comment: so what i do. when i am sending to multiple receipt i want to know which receipt is failure.is it possible?

Comment: you can make use of some other method with return type to perform the sending work. so, that you can make use of the return type to evaluate whether it is a success or not.

Comment: You can make ExchangePattern out capable and make use of any other method which returns the result.

Comment: Didn't that help you?

Comment: i try searching on apache camel site about ExchangePatter for email. but i did not get any idea